# woocommerce add item to cart with rest api

Tags: java, android, woocommerce

I want to add a product to cart using `woocommerce rest api`, I found the following endpoints to do this.

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wc/store/cart
```

but there is no document on how to use it.
how can I use it? or is there a tutorial for it?

Comment: https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Comment: @Stultuske the cart documentation does not exist in this link!

Comment: maybe because Cart is a plugin you need to buy additionally. Either way, that is the official documentation of woocommerce rest api. if it isn't in there, there isn't a (reliable) documentation for it. https://woocommerce.com/search/?q=cart&collections=product